# If condition not executes while mouse move fastly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CSS**

```
.selected
{
    background-color: Red;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#mytable tr', function (e)
{
    var currentColoumn = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
    if ($(this).find("td").eq(currentColoumn).hasClass('selected') == true) {                                     
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="mytable ">
   <tr>
      <td>
          9:30 AM
      </td>
      <td>
          30
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td class="selected">
          SELECTED
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have to check a condition in tr mouse move where if td has class selected then mouse move stops.
If condition not executes while mouse move fastly

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg58G/5/)

Comment: Why don't you use `.hover()` ?

Comment: mousehover event on cell

Comment: I see that you're trying to prevent the `mousemove` event from propagating, but without knowing what's listening above that, I can't really understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Christopher I have to check a condition in tr mouse move where if td has class selected then mouse move stops

Comment: see Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/Jg58G/5/

Comment: @Means you can't stop the users mouse movement! You can just prevent the effects coming from that event.

Comment: @Christopher  So what should i do...

Comment: I don't think you could do anything. This is OS / hardware / Browser limitation...

Comment: you also wouldn't **want** to do that. consider what if some website stopped *your* mouse movement.

Comment: Couldn't you just say `if ($(e.target).closest('td').hasClass('selected'))`...?  Why get the index of the TD, and then go find the TD with that index?  Seems like busywork...

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is your problem? What is the desired result? Are you trying to prevent the mouse from moving, or are you trying to to prevent a mouse move function from firing?

Comment: See in Demo fiddle..When i drag on cells while dragging i have check if condition cell having class selected..IF its true then stops cell dragging..when i drag on cells slowly then if condition executes while dragging fastly then if condition not executes

Comment: Hope my quetion understands you

Comment: if ($(this).find("td").eq(currentColoumn).hasClass('selected') == true)

Comment: See above if condition not executes while drag on cells fastly

Comment: mousemove can be an intensive event. There's no foolproof fix, but you might increase performance by making the mousemove callback function as simple as possible. The less code that has to be executed, the more sensitive the mousemove will be. Instead of trying to capture quick mouse movements, maybe you should embrace the idea of user intent instead. For example, the jquery hoverIntent plugin uses mouse velocity as a factor in determining whether a user actually intended to mouse over an area or not. This plugin often makes the user experience seem smoother and more polished.

Answer (score 3):

The way you're using `on` here, is attaching the event listener to the document, and apply the callback to any `mousemove` events on rows in the `#mytable` element. That means internally, the call to `on` is translated into a call to `delegate`.
Normally, I'm all for event delegation, for obvious reasons (performance being the most obvious of all). However, when you delegate mouse events, your handler is being called *every time the event is fired*. When doesn't a mouse move somewhere in the `document`? When the client is reading, the window is minimized or not in focus.

Though jQuery hides this, your code actually does this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e)
{
    var parent, target = (e = e || window.event).target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr')
    {//this reverse DOM lookup is probably cached, but anyway
        parent = target;
        while(parent = parent.parentNode)
        {//or something
            if (parent.getAttribute('id') === 'myTable')
            {
                break;
            }
            if (parent === document.body)
            {//not child of #myTable
                return e;
            }
        }
        if (yourCallbackFunction.apply(target, [e]) === false)
        {//remember: return false in jQ == preventDefault + stopPropagation:
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Your callback is only called when the element is a child of a `#myTable`, but each time the mouse moves, an event handler *is* being called!
When delegating events like this, it'd be wiser to do this:

```
$('#myTable').on('mousemove', 'tr', function()
{
    //your code here
});
```

This way, an event handler will only be called when the mousemove event occurs *inside* the `#myTable` element. Since that's all you're interested in, that's what you should do.

The fiddle you linked to is also *packed* with `live` calls. `live` has been deprecated for *years* now, one of the reasons being: it was slooow.
Another thing to look into if speed is an issue is: avoid excessive DOM calls, by using *closures* for example. DOM calls are slow!

If speed is *still* an issue, don't use jQuery: use VanillaJs, if done right... it'll always be faster than a lib

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach just needs some tweaking. The constraints can be calculated at the time a cell is clicked; as the mouse moves you know when to stop colouring the cells.

Here's a breakdown:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    document.onselectstart = function () { return false; }

    var $table = $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment'),
    columns = [],
    dragInfo = null;

    $table.find('td').each(function() {
        var i = $(this).index();
        (columns[i] = columns[i] || []).push(this);
    });
```

This creates a pivoted array so that you can reference each column more easily. This comes in handy later.

```
    $table.on('mouseup', function() {
        // reset selection
        dragInfo = null;
    });
```

This is the same as your previous code, except you may have noticed two differences:

1. I'm setting up the click event handler on `$table` instead of `document`; this prevents some overheads when clicks outside the table are received.
2. Because `.live()` is deprecated, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used instead.

Let's move on to the `mousedown` handler.

```
    $table.on('mousedown', 'td', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        columnIndex = $this.index();

        if ($this.is('.selected') || columnIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        var thisRow = $this.parent().index(),
        selectionRowAbove = -Infinity,
        selectionRowBelow = Infinity;

        $.each(columns[columnIndex], function(rowIndex) {
            if ($(this).is('.selected')) {
                if (rowIndex < thisRow && rowIndex > selectionRowAbove) {
                    selectionRowAbove = rowIndex;
                } else if (rowIndex > thisRow && rowIndex < selectionRowBelow) {
                    selectionRowBelow = rowIndex;
                }
            }
        });
```

By adding a listener on `td` instead of `tr` you don't have to find the nearest cell; it gets calculated for you. This part of the function works out the red cells above and below the current cell.

```
        // unmark cells
        $table.find(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");

        dragInfo = {
            column: columnIndex,
            enclosure: {
                above: selectionRowAbove,
                below: selectionRowBelow
            },
            min: thisRow,
            max: thisRow
        };

        $this.addClass('csstdhighlight');
    });
```

The last part of the function saves all the drag information that you will need later on.

```
    $table.on('mousemove', 'td', function() {
        if (!dragInfo) {
            return;
        }

        var $this = $(this),
        columnIndex = $this.index(),
        rowIndex = $this.parent().index();

        if (columnIndex != dragInfo.column || rowIndex == 0 ||  rowIndex <= dragInfo.enclosure.above || rowIndex >= dragInfo.enclosure.below) {
            dragInfo = null;
            return;
        }
```

These conditions make sure the selection stays within the bounds that we have determined earlier.

```
        // mark cells
        var cells = [columns[columnIndex][rowIndex]];
        while (dragInfo.min > rowIndex) {
            cells.push(columns[columnIndex][dragInfo.min--]);
        }
        while (dragInfo.max < rowIndex) {
            cells.push(columns[columnIndex][dragInfo.max++]);
        }
        $(cells).addClass('csstdhighlight');
    });
});
```

The last part of the function marks the selection; it does so by calculating the differences between the last invocation, so that you don't have to mark cells again.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg58G/9/)

Answer (score 0):

There is one semi-solution, however, that could be done.

Use CSS on the body to hide the actual mouse cursor, then display a fake mouse pointer (just a regular graphic) at the mouse location.

If the mouse pointer is out of bounds, stop the fake cursor at the bounding box.

I don't know what your use-case is, but it would be **MUCH** better if you don't hide the real mouse pointer, but display some kind of oversized mouse pointer in the bounding box.  Mostly the same effect and much more user friendly.

Comment: See in Demo fiddle..When i drag on cells while dragging i have check if condition cell having class selected..IF its true then stops cell dragging..when i drag on cells slowly then if condition executes while dragging fastly then if condition not executes

Comment: if ($(this).find("td").eq(currentColoumn).hasClass('selected') == true)

Comment: See above if condition not executes while drag on cells fastly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a diferent approach to deciding on wether a mousemove should stop highlighting a cell. Instead of "stoping when it goes over a cell with the class selected",

Try stoping if between the initial cell and the current cell exists a cell with the class selected. This ensures that if a fast movement prevents the mousemove event from being delegated to your "selected" cells it will still be able to detect that you have passed over one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem here is that the mouse does not stop on every single cell. The mouse usually looks like it moves continuously, but when I move it quickly, it jumps around, skipping large amounts of space in between.

I think you've already seen this affect. Hence, you are highlighting a range of cells, not just the one you are pointing to (current cell). However, you are only checking if the current cell is selected, not if any of the in between cells are selected.

The solution is to check all the in between cells to make sure that they are not selected. jQuery has a `filter` function that does that nicely. I've refactored your code to use filter:

```
$("#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr").live('mousemove', function (e) {
    // Compares with the last and next row index.
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    var currentColoumn = $(e.target).closest('td').index();

    var allRows = $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr');
    var previousRowIndex = parseInt(lastRow, 10);
    var currentRowIndex = parseInt(currentRow, 10);

    var traversedRows;
    if (previousRowIndex < currentRowIndex)
        traversedRows = allRows.slice(previousRowIndex, parseInt(currentRowIndex + 1));
    else {
        traversedRows = allRows.slice(currentRowIndex, previousRowIndex)
    }

    var affectedCells = traversedRows.children(':nth-child(' + parseInt(currentColoumn + 1) + ')');

    if ($(this).find("td").eq(currentColoumn).hasClass('selected') == true ||
       affectedCells.filter('.selected').length > 0) {
        if (flag != false) {
            flag = false;
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (currentRow == 0) {
        flag = false;
        return false;
    }
    //cross cell selection.
    if (colIndex != currentColoumn) {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }

    if (flag) {
        affectedCells.addClass('csstdhighlight');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/Jg58G/7/

There still exists an issue where some cells are supposed to be highlighted, but they are not. Now that you have the row of the selected cell, you can redo your slice logic to slice at the right place. I'll leave that part to you.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if this is precisely what you're aiming for, but it should be easy to adapt. Using mouseover cuts down on the calls, should have better performance.

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/VJG4F/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // setup
    var doc = this;
    doc.checkOver = false;
    doc.activeCell = {
        x: -1,
        y: -1
    };
    doc.lastCell = {
        x: -1,
        y: -1
    };
    doc.highlightClass = 'csstdhighlight';
    doc.selectionClass = 'selected';
    doc.selectionText = 'SELECTED';

    // start checking on mousedown
    $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        doc.checkOver = true;

        // set active and last cell for reference
        doc.lastCell.x = doc.activeCell.x = $(this).closest('td').index();
        doc.lastCell.y = doc.activeCell.y = $(this).closest("tr").index();

            // highlight selected cells
            var cellSelector = '#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr:eq(' + doc.activeCell.y + ') td:eq(' + doc.activeCell.x + ')';
            $(cellSelector).addClass(doc.highlightClass);

        // check for movement
        $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').on('mouseover', function (e) {
            if (!(doc.checkOver)) return;

            // get current cell for reference
            var currCell = {
                x: $(e.target).closest('td').index(),
                y: $(e.target).closest('tr').index()
            };

            // verify mouse is over a different cell
            if ( !((currCell.y != doc.lastCell.y && currCell.y != -1) || (currCell.x != doc.lastCell.x && currCell.x != -1)) ) return false;

            // make sure other cells are not highlighted
            $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').removeClass(doc.highlightClass);

            // highlight selected cells
            var topLeft = {
                x: Math.min(currCell.x, doc.activeCell.x),
                y: Math.min(currCell.y, doc.activeCell.y)
            };
            var botRight = {
                x: Math.max(currCell.x, doc.activeCell.x),
                y: Math.max(currCell.y, doc.activeCell.y)
            };

            for (var x=topLeft.x;x<=botRight.x;x++) {
                for (var y=topLeft.y;y<=botRight.y;y++) {
                    var cellSelector = '#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr:eq(' + y + ') td:eq(' + x + ')';
                    $(cellSelector).addClass(doc.highlightClass);
                }
            }

            // update last cell
            doc.lastCell.y = currCell.y;
            doc.lastCell.x = currCell.x;

            return false;
        });

        // check for mouseup
        $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').on('mouseup', function (e) {

            // stop checking for movement
            $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').off('mouseup');
            $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').off('mouseout');

            // get current cell for reference
            var currCell = {
                x: $(this).closest("td").index(),
                y: $(this).closest('tr').index()
            };

            // make sure cells are not highlighted
            $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment td').removeClass(doc.highlightClass);

            // select cells
            var topLeft = {
                x: Math.min(currCell.x, doc.activeCell.x),
                y: Math.min(currCell.y, doc.activeCell.y)
            };
            var botRight = {
                x: Math.max(currCell.x, doc.activeCell.x),
                y: Math.max(currCell.y, doc.activeCell.y)
            };

            // single cell - toggle
            if( topLeft.x == botRight.x && topLeft.y == botRight.y ) {
                var cellSelector = '#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr:eq(' + topLeft.y + ') td:eq(' + topLeft.x + ')';
                $(cellSelector).toggleClass(doc.selectionClass);
                if( $(cellSelector).text() == doc.selectionText ) $(cellSelector).text('');
                else $(cellSelector).text(doc.selectionText);

            // multi-cell, select all
            } else {
                for (var x=topLeft.x;x<=botRight.x;x++) {
                    for (var y=topLeft.y;y<=botRight.y;y++) {
                        var cellSelector = '#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr:eq(' + y + ') td:eq(' + x + ')';
                        $(cellSelector).addClass(doc.selectionClass);
                        $(cellSelector).text(doc.selectionText);
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset
            doc.checkOver = false;
            doc.activeCell.y = -1;
            doc.activeCell.x = -1;
            doc.lastCell.y = -1;
            doc.lastCell.x = -1;
            return false;
        });

        return false; // prevent default
    });

});
```